# How to create a new column for transposed data

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm attempting to transpose a row into a new column using the pandas dataframe. Visit ID is the unique identifier. I used df.pivot and df.melt but df.melt seems to do the opposite. I'm pretty new to Python and I gave it a start but I'm pretty lost.
Any suggestions?

**Current input:**

| Visit ID | DX Code | Insurance | Primary or Secondary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Aetna | Primary |
| 1 | 234 | Affinity | Secondary |
| 2 | 456 | VNS | Secondary |
| 2 | 789 | Medicare | Primary |

**Desired Output:**

| Visit ID | DX Code | DX Code2 | Primary | Secondary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 234 | Aetna | Affinity |
| 2 | 456 | 789 | Medicare | VNS |

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\TEST.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

# pivot = df.pivot(index='Visit ID', columns='DX Code', values = 'DX ID')
# print(pivot)

# melt = df.melt(value_name='DX Code', var_name='DX Code2')
# print(melt)
```

Comment: How does your input data frame look like?

Comment: I edited my post. Instead of "Current Output", I put "Current Input"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge`:

```
out = pd.merge(df[df['Primary or Secondary'] == 'Primary'],
               df[df['Primary or Secondary'] == 'Secondary'],
               on='Visit ID', suffixes=('', '2'))
```

The rest is just reformatting:

```
out = out[['Visit ID', 'DX Code', 'DX Code2', 'Insurance', 'Insurance2']] \
          .rename(columns={'Insurance': 'Primary', 'Insurance2': 'Secondary'})
```

```
>>> df
   Visit ID  DX Code  DX Code2   Primary Secondary
0         1      123       234     Aetna  Affinity
1         2      789       456  Medicare       VNS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which uses pandas as backend but implements `dplyr`-like syntax:

```py
>>> from datar.all import c, f, tribble, tibble, rep, paste0, pivot_wider
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.Visit_ID, f.DX_Code, f.Insurance, f.Primary_or_Secondary,
...     1,          123,       "Aetna",     "Primary",
...     1,          234,       "Affinity",  "Secondary",
...     2,          456,       "VNS",       "Secondary",
...     2,          789,       "Medicare",  "Primary",
... )
>>> df
   Visit_ID  DX_Code Insurance Primary_or_Secondary
    <int64>  <int64>  <object>             <object>
0         1      123     Aetna              Primary
1         1      234  Affinity            Secondary
2         2      456       VNS            Secondary
3         2      789  Medicare              Primary

>>> # Create a new df with names and values
>>> df2 = tibble(
...     Visit_ID=rep(df.Visit_ID, 2),
...     name=c(paste0("DX Code", rep(c("", "2"), 2)), df.Primary_or_Secondary),
...     value=c(df.DX_Code, df.Insurance)
... )
>>> 
>>> df2
   Visit_ID       name     value
    <int64>   <object>  <object>
0         1    DX Code       123
1         1   DX Code2       234
2         2    DX Code       456
3         2   DX Code2       789
4         1    Primary     Aetna
5         1  Secondary  Affinity
6         2  Secondary       VNS
7         2    Primary  Medicare
>>> df2 >> pivot_wider()
   Visit_ID  DX Code DX Code2   Primary Secondary
    <int64> <object> <object>  <object>  <object>
0         1      123      234     Aetna  Affinity
1         2      456      789  Medicare       VNS
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the datar package.